# Pass the object to Android download manager with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-download-manager

I am developing ReactJS application using Apache Cordova. One of the features is the object downloading (the BLOB object is built with application code, then should be downloaded as a file). It works fine in browser but I get completely stuck to get it working in WebView under Android.

"Response.ContentType=.... etc"  is well-known approach to launch file downloading in browser, and this response should be built on server and rendered to browser. But in our case, we have already got the response because Javascript being executed is itself the part of response, and we have no server, able to render relevant response. I tried to google for a solution and something like

```
document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +
                         encodeURIComponent(dataToDownload);
}
```

was the only I have found. I have to admit that it does not work neither in browser, nor on the phone, and url-encoding of large binary object looks quirky.

I guess that even if I was able to make relevant response it would not work in Webview and I likely have to use Java plugins in order to launch Android download manager (I am absolutely not familiar with Java and Android development stuff and deduced from googling that "Download manager" is the process that  launches on the phone when user downloads file in a browser running on Android, or installs the application from Playmarket or downloads file with bluetooth etc. And it displays incoming file notification in phone notification bar and brings the file to default Download directory. Correct me if I am wrong because  will use the term "Download manager" later in a meaning I just have mentioned)

What has surprised me is that the functionality which supposed to be widely used is absolute obscure in terms of googling for the solution. It looks like nobody needs it or it is so simple and obvious that nobody experiences any problems.

Yes, I have found some plugins like FileTransfer or Background Download Manager but none of them appeared to do that I need. Tried both and they seem to be destined to download external resource and save it to local file without involving Download Manager. However I failed to make working even it. Tried to pass existing URLs there and code either hung or raised error handler with errors like "External storage must be used" (BTW I have no idea how to match file:/// resources in Android with phone storage folders and googled for it. But all solutions use android ENVIRONMENT object which is inaccessible in Cordova application and it is nowhere explained how to attach it to Cordova)

The farther I search the more obscure found plugins are. The last found [plugin](http://plugreg.com/plugin/aenario/cordova-downloadmanager) is.

is supposed to do that we need (for now I omit the issue how to build BLOB object to android-compatible Uri which should be a source for our downloading and anticipating a long banging head against the wall, but for now I want at least launch download for some existing resource in Internet)

What is suspicious in this plugin that it requires PATH as parameter. Path does not look like what we need, because file should save with default Android downloading functionality and placed to default Downloads folder. So the file name is only we need in this case.

But this plugin has no readme and seems to be underdone or not working. It causes  failure when I build .apk with cordova. Learning it deeper, I found that Java compiler curses on omitted ';' in .java plugin file. I am unfamiliar with java, but having fixed missing semi-columns , ran to another chain of issues - compiler became curse on every dependency saying that it is unknown symbols. Indeed neither of them were listed in namespaces import section, some I managed to fix (e.g unknown 'File' by adding 'import java.io.*') but some I do now know where to get. So the plugin seems to be non-functional or I miss some prerequisites for installation (however I managed to install other plugins successfully)

Eventually I have spend 3 days with no avail and I wonder why such a common function is demanded and discussed so seldom

Any suggestions or especially working plugins/examples are very much appreciated. I do not believe that is  not achievable in Cordova just to simply make file to download.

Comment: Instead of being sorry for the long message you could try and shorten it a bit. It's hard to read as it is.

Comment: You are right, nobody will read such a long message. I wanted to share my experience with this issue and prevent people to give  hints which  already proved to be not relevant. But I have to agree with you, it's better to explain the issue briefly otherwise it won't be read.

so, placed it here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464331/forward-custom-content-for-downloading-on-android-phone

Comment: Okay. please ask for this post to be deleted